# Router Provider MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

If I wanted to force the routing map and allow the quantity value to be a decimal
how should I change it using regular expressions?

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute(
    "AddProduct-Catalog",
    "addproduct/catalog/{productId}/{shoppingTypeId}/{quantity}",
    new { controller = "Shopping", action = "AddProduct_Catalog"},
    new { productId = @"\d+", shoppingTypeId = @"\d+", quantity=@"\d+" },
    new[] { "BBC.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

Currently if I pass `addproduct/catalog/34/1/5` OK

if I pass `addproduct/catalog/34/1/5.5` NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using query string instead of int/decimal/float for decimals 
so it will look like

```
addproduct/catalog/34/1/?quantity=5.5
```

and in controller parse it

```
public ActionResult Catalog(string quantity){
   var myval = (decimal)quantity;
}
```